# Post loop is not working correctly on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a separate page for blog posts on my website (WordPress). I Used this code for showing 6 last posts:

```html
<div class="container">

 <div class="entry-content">

  <div class="last-posts">

   <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=6' ); ?>
   <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="post-item">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank">
      <figure><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></figure>
     </a>
     <div class="post-detail">
      <h3>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank">
        <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
       </a>
      </h3>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <?php
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
   
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, this loop works from "container" class to the end of the code, not just 6 last posts. This loads all 6 posts 6 times.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think you can have spaces around the `->` in `$the_query -> have_posts()` & `$the_query -> the_post()` so try `<?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI you are making a small mistake in the WP_Query 
please try the following line.

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page' => 6 ); ?>
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' =>6, 'post_type' => 'post','order'=>'desc','post_status'=>'publish');
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```